# Polynomials and Inner Product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials

**Question:** $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ polynomials with degree less than or equal to $n$. Show that there exists $g(x) \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that for every $f(x) \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$, $$f(0) =  \int_{-2}^{2} f(x)g(x) \,dx. $$

Well, I thought of starting with defining as $<f(x),g(x)> \ =  \ \int_{-2}^{2} f(x)g(x) \,dx $ over these real polynomials. However, I am looking for help to take the first step. Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $g$ and $h$ supposed to be the same polynomial?

Comment: @FrankSeidl Yes. Edited. Sorry for inconvention.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track ! Hint : how can you link this to the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) ?